# Mysql --> Mysqli

Tags: php

hi i need some help again. 
can anyone do me a favor to convert my code from Mysql --> Mysqli
I've been using mysql so im not that familiar yet with mysqli
thanks in advance

Here is my php code that i want to convert

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT sched_ID, venue FROM tblschedule"); 
    echo '<select id="sched_ID" name="sched_ID"  class="form-control" >';
    echo '<option>-- Select Venue --</option>';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) 
    {
        echo '<option value="'.$row['sched_ID'].'">'.$row['venue'].'</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
 ?>
```

Comment: There is a manual, it shows everything you need. We won't convert code for you. We will help you with issues you have.

Comment: @chris85 *"We won't..."* - you and I lol, but someone did VVVVVVVV

Comment: @Fred-ii- good point. I guess I'll leave a this by the hole, https://www.organicfacts.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Carrot1.jpg.

Comment: @chris85 as Bugs Bunny would say: *"Lotsa iron"*

Comment: @chris85 I guess that was meant for the OP, as in "feeding them", correct? ;-) I usually like to teach them how to fish, rather than just throwing them a halibut or something.

Comment: This question showed 0% percent effort and you learned nothing.

Comment: @Fred-ii- for the answerer to feed the rabbit so the hole stops growing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To learn how to use mysqli syntax, please check the documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Seems to me the mysqli syntax for your code would be:

```
<?php

    $query = "SELECT sched_ID, venue FROM tblschedule"; 
    echo '<select id="sched_ID" name="sched_ID"  class="form-control" >';
    echo '<option>-- Select Venue --</option>';
    $result = mysqli_query($dbconnection, $query) or die(mysqli_error($dbconnection));
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['sched_ID'].'">'.$row['venue'].'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
 ?>
```